# grep command in shell is taking too long

Tags: shell, grep

Below is the part of my shell program where the grep command is taking too long to produce result ,

```
logdir="/logs/orderjob"
recentorderjobFile=$(ls -t $logdir/orderjob* | head -n1)
start=`grep 'TWS has called script' $recentorderjobFile`
```

But i am not seeing any slowness when manually run the grep command for the log file.

```
grep 'TWS has called script' orderjob_12042018.log
```

Why the grep command in start variable is taking long time/not producing the results?.How can i modify the command to get the expected results quickly?.

Comment: Are you sure you passed it a filename?

Comment: likely the OS is buffering the output of the command that fills up the logFile. Search here for `[linux] unbuffer` for information on how to remedy that. Good luck.

Comment: How big is the file? How long is "too long"? Is it taking too long to start producing output, or too long to finish?

Comment: @KeithThompson - The file size is only 52kb, its taking too long to finish, I can say its just not giving me any results even after 5 minutes.So i normally press ctrl+C to cancel the operation

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Yes , I am passing the file name. it takes long time even if i modify the command like start=`grep 'TWS has called script' orderjob_12042018.log`

Comment: Have you absolutely confirmed that `$recentorderjobFile` is `orderjob_12042018.log`? Is your script in the correct directory when it invokes the `grep` command? Try temporarily adding `echo ">>> In $(pwd), recentorderjobFile=$recentorderjobFile"` just before the `grep` command.

Comment: @simbu3306 : Run it with `set -x`. I bet that in your script, *recentorderjobFile* is empty.